# Getting error Query was empty while insert new data

Tags: php

I am writing a script to insert a new data into `Database`, but I keep getting an error:-

> Notice: Undefined index: priceBig in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\admin\add.php on line 12

Am I missing something?

How can I fix this error? Any help would be great. Thank you

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_code` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `product_desc` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `product_img_name` varchar(60),
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `price_big` decimal (10,2) ,
  `product_type` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `product_code` (`product_code`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


require("config.php");
$status = "";
if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new']==1){
    $id                 = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $product_code       = $_REQUEST['product_code'];
    $product_name       = $_REQUEST['product_name'];
    $product_desc       = $_REQUEST['product_desc'];
    $product_img_name   = $_REQUEST['product_img_name'];
    $price              = $_REQUEST['price'];
    $priceBig           = $_REQUEST['priceBig'];
    $product_type       = $_REQUEST['product_type'];
    // $submittedby     = $_SESSION["username"];
    $ins_query          = "INSERT INTO items(id, product_code, product_name, product_desc, product_img_name, price, priceBig, product_type) VALUES
        ('$id','$product_code', '$product_name', '$product_desc', '$product_img_name', '$price', '$priceBig', '$product_type')";
    mysql_query($ins_query) or die(mysql_error());
    $status = "New Record Inserted Successfully.</br></br><a href='admin.php?appetizers_Soup'>View Inserted Record</a>";
}


<form name="form" method="post" action="add.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="new" value="1" />
    <p><input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Enter ID" required /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="product_code" placeholder="Enter Product Code" required /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="product_name" placeholder="Enter Product Name" required /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="product_desc" placeholder="Enter Product Description" required /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="product_img_name" placeholder="Enter Product Image" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Enter Price 1" required /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="priceBig" placeholder="Enter Price 2" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="product_type" placeholder="Enter Product Type" required /></p>
    <p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: `$_REQUEST['priceBig']` is simply not defined.

Comment: maybe try to clear your cache or open your script to cognito mode and try to use $_POST rather than $_REQUEST

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
 if(isset($_REQUEST['priceBig'])){
       $priceBig = $_REQUEST['priceBig'];
 } else{
        $priceBig = "";
 }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

`$_REQUEST['priceBig']` simply is not defined.

If it's no problem to write a empty field or just NULL to your table you could resolve that by checking if `$_REQUEST['priceBig']` is set or is empty and then define it as NULL:

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['priceBig'])){
    $priceBig = NULL;
}else{
    $priceBig = $_REQUEST['priceBig'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I got `Query was empty`. Either I enter NULL or leave the input empty. Any idea?

Comment: It could be the table is set up to not accept NULL values, then try:     `$priceBig = '';` as this is empty and not NULL.

Comment: I still get the same error. I updated my code for creating table. There are only columns that accept NULL

Comment: write your query to a variable: `$query = "insert into...";` and then dump it to see if the query is correct: `var_dump($query);` (and maybe test it in a mysql console)

Comment: Thank you, I found the problem is from connect database file. I figured out.